# Azure DocumentDB minimum billing time

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

DcoumentDB has a minimum billing time of 1 hour.

How much would the following cost?

- I create a collection (400Ru/s) at time 01:00
- I upgrade the collection 1000Ru/s to a total of 1400Ru/s at time 01:30
- I downgrade the collection back to 400Ru/s at time 02:15
- I delete the collection at 02:45

Will I be charged 400Ru/s for 2 hours + 1000Ru/s for 1 hour

Or

Will I be charged 400Ru/s + 1000Ru/s for 2 hours?

I ask as it would depend on how the billing clock works, I could see it being the latter as I was at 1400Ru/s at 01:00 & 02:00 hours. Although I only used the upgrade for less than 1 hour.

Answer (score 2):

Great question! Based on the FAQs provided [`here`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/cosmos-db/), you will be charged for 1400RU/s for both hours. If I am understanding the FAQs correctly, you will be charged the maximum RU/s provisioned in a clock hour (i.e. between 1:00 and 2:00, 2:00 and 3:00 etc.)

From the documentation link:

> **What if my container is active for less than an hour?**
>
> You are billed the flat rate for each hour the container exists,
>   regardless of usage or if the container is active for less than an
>   hour. For example, if you create a container and delete it 5 minutes
>   later, your bill will reflect a charge for 1 unit hour.

---

> **When does the billing rate change after I upgrade a container?**
>
> If you define your own performance for a container and you upgrade at
>   9:30AM from 400 RUs to 1,000 RUs and downgrade at 10:45AM back to 400
>   RUs, you will be charged for two hours of 1,000 RUs.